# Find outer-line of given shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

I have various solid shapes that i need to find the outer-lines for.

I get the shapes from an API, as a list of x,y-coordinates for every pixel in the shape. I would like to remove the "filler points" so i only have a list of the "outer-line", the red pixels in this image:

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: Aren't shapes defined by their outlines anyway?

Comment: As i'm getting my shapes from an API they are not defined that way, i get the coordinates for every pixel in the filled shape.

Comment: But you said you wanted pixel positions anyway?

Comment: Yes, but ONLY the outer line, no the pixels filling the shpe. I need some kind of formula to calculate which pixels are the actual line and which are the filled ones.

Comment: Having shapes defined in pixels sound very strange and you only need pixels when rendering a shape.  Storing shapes using bezier curves or lines is much more flexible and less expensive.  I would consider using a different API.

Comment: I can't use another API, this is what i have to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up that image and zoom in on it, you can easily see what distinguishes the red pixels from the blue ones: a red pixel has at least one white pixel either directly above, below, to the left or to the right of it, whereas a blue pixel has zero. Diagonals don't count.

So you can find the outer-line of the shape (the red pixels) with the following algorithm, given a list of pixel co-ordinates:

- Convert all the pixel co-ordinates to integers if they aren't already.
- Iterate through all the points in the list and find the min and max x and y co-ordinates.
- Create an array with size [(max y - min y) + 1][(max x - min x) + 1] and set all the elements to 0
- Iterate through all the points in the list and set array[point y - min y][point x - min x] to 1
- Create an empty list for your outer-line co-ordinates
- Iterate through the array, and for each element array[y][x]:

  - If array[y][x] equals 1 AND (array[y-1][x] equals 0 OR array[y+1][x] equals 0 OR array[y][x-1] equals 0 OR array[y][x+1] equals 0), then:

    - add (x + min x, y + min y) to the list of outer-line points.

Be careful that (max y - min y) and (max x - min x) are not to large, or you might get an out of memory error when trying to allocate the array. Also, to avoid index out of bounds errors when checking the array, just add any pixel at the edges of the array (x or y = 0, x or y = x or y array size - 1) where array[y][x] equals 1 to the list and avoid the other checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAShapeLayer, 
here is one example for how to achieve that.

```
CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shape.frame = self.label.bounds; // Give your created shape bounds
shape.path = maskPath.CGPath;
shape.lineWidth = 3.0f;
shape.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
[self.label.layer addSublayer:shape];
```

You can use UIBiezerPath also, for connecting points,
Here is a example of that

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

// Set the starting point of the shape.
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 0.0)];

// Draw the lines.
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 40.0)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(160, 140)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0, 140)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 40.0)];

// To make path closed you can use this
[aPath closePath];
```

Hope this helps you, Happy coding..

Comment: I don't know the bounds though, i only got a set of pixels.

Comment: I've edited my answer @LordVermillion, please review it once.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is still. I have an amount of coordinates, some are for the contour and some are for the filling. I need an algorithm to get only the contour coordinates.

Comment: okk., have you referred some OpneCV libraries which are available on https://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls also. You can find some solution from there as well. @LordVermillion